# Hspice to Ltspice conversion

Tags: ltspice, hspice, ibis

Has anyone had any luck converting Hspice or IBIS model files to formats LtSpice can use? Any help much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Quoting Mike Engelhardt (who develops and maintains LTspice):

> LTspice understands some hspice syntax.  For example, it understands
>   single quotes for parameter substitution as well as ".lib 'file.lib'
>   FAST" syntax.  It won't usually be able to understand a '$' symbol as
>   the start of a comment in-line. Usually this is enough to be able to
>   run 3rd party foundry BSIM3 models without modification as long as all
>   dimensions, areas, and perimeters are specified.  LTspice development
>   policy is that went there is a conflict between PSpice and hspice
>   syntax, LTspice will follow PSpice because it a more widely used
>   standard.

and also,

> LTspice does not do the Philips MOS 9 device.  As I recall, that model
>   is now open sourced but it is in FORTRAN.  Also, I should mention that
>   a general rule is that LTspice does not do the hspice-specific
>   semiconductor enhancements.  You can use the 2nd edition of
>   *Semiconductor Device Modeling with SPICE* by G. Massobrio and P. Antognetti as a good reference for hspice vs PSpice device
>   enhancements. The PSpice enhancements in that book can be used as an
>   LTspice manual.

and then on IBIS,

> No, IBIS isn't in LTspice.  I think IBIS was an Intel invention that
>   allowed them to give behavioral descriptions of their I/O pins without
>   giving out implementation details.
>
> Anyway, I think IBIS amounts largely to an IV curve. The DC curve you
>   can put in an IV lookup table.  To do the dynamic behavior, you're
>   better off with some kind of transistor level model of the device. 
>   Attached is an example of using a lookup table in a current source. I
>   don't know if it's otherwise documented anywhere.
>
> ```
> Version 4
> SHEET 1 880 680
> WIRE -32 320 -32 288
> WIRE -32 208 -32 176
> WIRE -32 176 -160 176
> WIRE -160 176 -160 208
> WIRE -160 288 -160 320
> FLAG -160 320 0
> FLAG -32 320 0
> SYMBOL current -32 208 R0
> SYMATTR InstName I1
> SYMATTR Value tbl(-5 -1 -2 -.5 0 0 1 1 5 2)
> SYMBOL voltage -160 192 R0
> SYMATTR InstName V1
> SYMATTR Value 0
> TEXT -152 368 Left 0 !.dc V1 -5 5 1m
> ```

But from someone else on IBIS and LTspice:

> I use a free utility from IntuSoft called IBIS2SPICE.
>
> It reads in IBIS models (up to version 2.1) and generates an
>   equivalent    behavioural spice model. It's originally intended to
>   generate a model  compatible with Intusoft's spice, but can be
>   configureed to generate  models for other spices based on a template
>   file. There's a templeate  file available on the net somewhere to
>   configure it for PSpice models.
>
> I can't really vouch for the accuracy of the models it generates, and 
>   it's limited to IBIS version 2.1.
>
> Generally it would be a great feature to have in LTSpice, but I guess 
>   it's not a priority for LT's chip designers, IBIS tends to be used 
>   primarily by board designers for board level Signal Integity analysis.

The above comments are from some years ago. Perhaps that will help some.

Comment: @Chrispy No problem. I just went to the LTspice Yahoo group and did some searches for you. You may want to leave this open for a little longer, to see if anyone else has any additions. But at some point, when you feel it's time, feel free to close it.